# Why does Google Docs Conditional Formatting with custom formula not work?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I am attempting to conditionally format a column of numbers to highlight those that are equal to the maximum. For example, if the column has these values 3,5,8,4,8,2,8,7

I want the 8s (in the 3rd, 5th and 7th rows) to be formatted.

I am selecting the row, right-clicking to choose "Conditional Formatting", selecting "is equal to" from the "Format cell is..." dropdown, and typing in "=MAX(A1:A8)" for the custom formula.

The cells that equal the max (8) have the conditional formatting correctly applied, but the final item in the column (the 7) has the conditional formatting *incorrectly* applied.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is a [link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J2LbfE-rhTRKpMQnkOCVhHh7VZT750wU3OaxFrTEojo/edit?usp=sharing) (non-editable).

I've noticed the same problem with other columns of numbers — the maximum values have the formatting applied (as expected), but some other numbers in the column always have the formatting incorrectly applied (unexpected).

Comment: I realize that screenshot shows the formula including an extra two cells (A9 and A10), but I get the same incorrect result if the formula is changed to "=max(A1:A8)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using relative addressing so that the 7 in A8 is actually the maximum of A8:A15.

Use the **$** absolute anchor to lock the rows with `=MAX(a$1:a$8)` or if the conditional format range extends laterally, `=MAX($a$1:$a$8)`.